# google client php library blogger

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-client

### i am use google client library to login but when i use (Google_Service_Blogger) for example insert or get post's i have this error message.

The request did not specify any referer. Please ensure that the client is sending referer or use the API Console to remove the referer restrictions.

this is message say his don't need any redirect URIs but to login i need redirect URIs .

how can i deal with it.

i'm tried :-

1. create new object from Google_Client without redirectUri
2. create new Oauth Id with out redirect url (But i cant login with it)